# Custom validator to compare two fields

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

I have two fields - StartTime and EndTime - which are both of the type time.Time and they are both within the same struct. How would one go about create a custom validator to ensure that EndTime is within 24 hours of StartTime? I am having trouble setting up the validator.Func to get both field values so that I may compare them (which I know how to do).

```
var validEndTime validator.Func = func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    endTime, ok := fl.F().Interface().(time.Time)

    if ok {
        today := time.Now()
        if today.After(date) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This is the example function I have started to write.

Answer (score 1):

you  can  use `fl.Parent()`  to get the struct

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

// Booking contains binded and validated data.
type Booking struct {
    CheckIn  time.Time `form:"check_in" binding:"required,bookabledate" time_format:"2006-01-02"`
    CheckOut time.Time `form:"check_out" binding:"required" time_format:"2006-01-02"`
}

var bookableDate validator.Func = func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    date, ok := fl.Field().Interface().(time.Time)
    if ok {
        booking, ok2 := fl.Parent().Interface().(*Booking)
        if ok2 && booking.CheckOut.Unix() - date.Unix() > 24*3600 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    route := gin.Default()

    if v, ok := binding.Validator.Engine().(*validator.Validate); ok {
        v.RegisterValidation("bookabledate", bookableDate)
    }

    route.GET("/bookable", getBookable)
    route.Run(":8085")
}

func getBookable(c *gin.Context) {
    var b Booking
    if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&b, binding.Query); err == nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Booking dates are valid!"})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    }
}
```